# Uri.parse(), how to get the encoding correct?

Tags: java, android, uri, percent-encoding

I am doing an application where I have to read a URL from a webpage as a String[Its not the address of the page]. The URL that I will be reading contains query string, and I specifically need two queries from that URL. So I am using the `Uri` class available in Android. Now, the problem lies in the encoding/format of the URL and the query. One of the queries that I need is always an URL. Sometimes the query URL is %-encoded and sometimes not.

The URLs can be like the following :

**Case 1 :**

> http://www.example.com/example/example.aspx?file=http%3A%2F%2FXX.XXX.XX.XXX%2FExample.file%3Ftoken%3D9dacfc85

**Case 2 :**

> http://www.example.com/example/example.aspx?file=http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/Example.file?token=9dacfc85

How do I get the correct Url contained in the `file=` query?

I am using the following [to accomplish the said work universally] :

```
Uri.decode(urlString.getQueryParameter("file"));
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

---

### **UPDATE**

I have decided to first encode the whole URL regardless of its value and then get the query parameter. Theoretically, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncertain about the type of URL you would get then I would suggest you to decode every URL you get from the parameter. And when you need to use it then you can encode it.

As per my knowledge, you are doing it right.

Comment: That's not it. I know how to decode a URL. And URLDecoder AFAIK is deprecated. But I cannot determine how will the URL be handled in both the cases and which one is the correct one.